# VBA Code for Filtering up through the current month

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet of work orders that have a column of complete by dates. I am trying to filter it down to show all orders with dates in the past going through to the end of the current month (EX: all past orders-End of July 2017).

The current code I'm am using works, but for some reason will not return 7/31/2017. It will return all prior date up to 7/30/2017. Can someone please help.

```
Sub Macro3()
Dim dtStart As Date
Dim dtFinal As Date

dtStart = CDate(Evaluate("DATE(YEAR(NOW()),-1,1)"))
dtFinal = CDate(Evaluate("EOMONTH(NOW(),0)"))

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$N$709").AutoFilter 13, ">=" & dtStart, xlAnd, "<=" & 
dtFinal, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dtFinal` is July 31, 2017 at 12:00am. You will want to make your final date August 1 and then change your filter from `"<="` to `"<"`.

Comment: This worked! The data I have is from a Dynamics AX set, so it was listing the time at 7am, not 12am (i don't really need to worry about the time, just the date). I just needed to correct that. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `WorksheetFunction.EoMonth` function, and the `DateSerial`, and replace your `Now` with `Date`, since you don't need to mess with the hours.

Try the line below instead your entire code:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:N709").AutoFilter 13, ">=" & DateSerial(Year(Date), -1, 1), _
                              xlAnd, "<=" & WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Date, 0), _
                              Operator:=xlFilterDynamic
```

Comment: I tried this, but it still was not listing 7/31. @davidmneedham solution worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: @Emartin1863  it's because your cells have time values, if you format them as date only, like "ddmmyyyy", it will work for you.

Comment: WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Date, 0) still evaluates to July 31, 2017 at 12:00am. Your solution would work if all of Emartin1863's completion-date values did not include a time.

Comment: @davidmneedham  did you test it? Because I'm using this method for quite some time, and having dates (without time in them ) has worked for me

Comment: @ShaiRado. Yes, we are in agreement. I am saying the method does not work since the values in column M are not whole numbers, they are dates with time. Excel is comparing 42947.29 (date with time value for July 31, 2017 7am) to 42947.00.